# Integral solving with complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to solve this integral but I don't know where to start.

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+16}dx$

Comment: Consider the contour integral $\oint\limits_{C}\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+16} \; dz$. Then taking the imaginary part.

Comment: Do I have to use the Residue Theorem or can I solve it any other way?

Comment: I mean, the Residue Theorem is the fastest way to solve it.  I cannot think of any other techniques that would work better right now.